# Android : `androidx.navigation.NavArgs` not found

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, navigationcontroller

I fetch this below code from 
[image: From Codelab for navigation controller]

But getting this below error: spend already more the 3 hours but not any success. 
[image: Here is my error]

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: `DeepLinkFragmentArgs`
`FlowStepFragmentArgs`
`FlowStepFragmentDirections` this all are auto generated class.

Answer (score 17):

Change this

```
  implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
  implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
```

to this:

```
  implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
  implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
```

**Notice** that **android.arch.navigation** is replaced with **androidx.navigation**

also, make sure to apply this plugin on top of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

and this to the dependencies to the project level build.gradle:

```
 classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-rc01"
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using kotlin and androidX than replace this

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

with

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

and in project level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha01"
}
```

on app level build.gradle

```
def nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha01"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

If you are using kotlin Ktx

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

Hope this will help other people also. It helps me too

Answer (score 1):

**Another possible case:**

Check in your code that you have actually **defined argument tag in the xml file** (sender && receiver).

In another case, Args will not be generated.

Following code will **not** generate Args:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/receiverFragment"
    android:name="com.example.app.ReceiverFragment"
    android:label="ReceiverFragment" >
</fragment>
```

**Following code will generate Args**:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/receiverFragment"
    android:name="com.example.app.ReceiverFragment"
    android:label="ReceiverFragment" >
    <argument
        android:name="myArgument"
        app:argType="integer"
        app:nullable="false" />
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle app level add this:

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

**Update:**

This codelab is very old try not updating libraries.

Comment: `apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
 ` Already there in app level gradle.

Comment: What version of android studio you're using.

Comment: Android studio 3.3.1

Comment: or delete whole build folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189304/discussion-between-hussnain-haidar-and-prashant-jajal).

Answer (score 0):

> Try to add

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha05"
```

> Instead of

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-rc02"
```

Comment: Could not find androidx.navigation:safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-rc02.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.3.1 of Android Studio have similar problems like this but solution is simple. Close project and Import your project again. You will see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything which is written above i.e adding all plugins and dependencies (which is completely right though) but I was doing this silly mistake ->
**I was creating navArgs variable outside the fragment**

**Don't** **->**

```
private val args by navArgs<VideoCallFragmentArgs>()

class YourFragment : Fragment() {

     override fun onCreateView(
      inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?
          ): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_call, container, false)
}
}
```

**Always create navArgs variable inside the fragment.**
**Do ->**

```
class YourFragment : Fragment() {

private val args by navArgs<VideoCallFragmentArgs>()

     override fun onCreateView(
      inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?
          ): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_call, container, false)
}
}
```