# Cannot access 'kotlin.Lazy' which is a supertype of 'androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy'

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to receive data in a fragment by safeargs. While delegating SendCashFragmentArgs by navArgs() its throwing : ["Cannot access 'kotlin.Lazy' which is a supertype of 'androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7n4V.png)

**gradle(Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    ext.nav_version = "2.3.5"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle(app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aj19990321.navigationcomponenetu4u"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //val nav_version = "2.3.5"

    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

}
```

Comment: refer this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181024

Comment: still the error is not solved

Comment: I have find out the solution !! changing this `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'` into `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'` is solving my problem. But I don't have any explanation ? can explain this ?